# Aws batch how to change the storage capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have some tar.gz archive on S3 glacier deep archive.
I would like to decompress them as soon as they are restored automatically, so I thought of using a lambda function which launches a batch job (some archives are too big to be decompressed directly with lambda).
What I would like to know is if there is a simple way to modify the temporary storage space accessible to my job? I saw that i can add ebs storage with a launch template, but the idea would be to have an amount of storage that is adapted to each archive. In other words have a lambda function that retrieves the size of the archive and launches the batch job with enough space. I specify that the size of the archives is very variable, from a few Go to a few To.

Comment: Acctually yes because with efs it's the same, i need to include the size on the launch template so i can't modify it for each jobs. But i will try if pipe from and to S3 is possible or not with an untar command between.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? –

Answer (score 2):

Probably [EFS](https://EFS%20volumes) would be the easiest:

> Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS) provides simple, **scalable file storage** for use with your AWS Batch jobs.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/